# RequiredFieldValidator doesn't work when submitting form after Posting back by TextChanged event to the Textbox

Tags: asp.net, textbox, requiredfieldvalidator, autopostback

In my `.aspx` form I have a text box with `Autopostback=True`.
I also set a RequiredFieldValidator next to it. But when Posting back by TextChanged event of my text box, my RequiredFieldValidator appears but still I can submit my form with nothing in the text box!

What is wrong, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Hey mate, I know this was a while ago but, did you eventually find a solution? cheers

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the textbox's CausesValidation property to true (it's set to false by default for textboxes).

Comment: thank you but still the form submits. How do I change the code so that the form doesn't submit?

Comment: I tested the scenario you've given and it worked. Maybe you should post some of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Give both the text box and the submit button the same validation group.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn" Text="button" CausesValidation="true" runat="server"/>
```

and make sure that `ControlToValidate=""` has same name as the `<asp:texbox/>`has

the best way to do is just right below `TextBox` field type `<asp:Required` and when the options come just pres **TAB Button** **twice**