# postback hide requirefieldvalidator asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator, autopostback

i am working with WepApplication and
the problem is i have one textbox with autopostback="true" and
some other textboxes and dropdowns with Validators like requirefield n regularexpression etc..
when i Click on "Submit" button,

Form is validated client side and All Requirefiled validators shows but after this problem starts when i changes text on textbox(autopostback=true") all validators are hide...
**but note one thing i want to fire OnTextChanged event** bz if i add **CausesValidation="true"** it will not call **OnTextChanged**

so is there any way to show validator(messages) even page autopostbacked....

help me plz.

thanx in advance...

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182150/autopostback-true-for-a-textbox-and-requiredfieldvalidator-next-to-it-but-when-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `CauseValidation` property of the `TextBox` to *true*.

Comment: yaa you are right but another thing is i have textchanged event to do somthing when textchanged n then i have to show validators. thn ??

Comment: @Jax: implement it in client side script then.

Comment: but how ? and i want like if submit button was clicked and then postback is done and then validator will be shown...?? if submit button was not clicked i dnt need to show validators on postback

Comment: @Jax: try calling the Validate method of the Validator controls in the TextChanged event handler.